# Strange problem with multiple polar plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've run into a strange issue plotting two ellipses on a single polar plot with matplotlib. Here's my Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def EllipseRadius(a, b, angle):
    return a * b / np.sqrt((b * np.cos(angle)) ** 2 + (a * np.sin(angle)) ** 2)

ell_a = 9   # Outer ellipse semi-major axis
ell_b = 1   # Outer ellipse semi-minor axis
ell_k = 0.1 # Ratio of inner ellipse to outer ellipse

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')

# First ellipse
angles1 = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
rs1 = EllipseRadius(ell_a, ell_b, angles1)
ax.plot(angles1, rs1)

# Second ellipse
angles2 = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
rs2 = EllipseRadius(ell_k*ell_a, ell_k*ell_b, angles2)
ax.plot(angles2, rs2)

##for i in range(len(angles1)):
##    print(angles1[i], rs1[i], rs2[i])

plt.show()
```

If I run this code, here's what I see:

[image: Plot showing the issue]

Note the central "bulge" in both ellipses. Strangely, if I comment out the larger ellipse (labeled "first ellipse" in the code above), here's the output:

[image]

That looks a lot more like what I expected. If I comment out the other ellipse instead, I get another great looking ellipse. So, for some reason, if I plot just either ellipse alone, it looks great, but if I plot both, they develop this strange shape.

I am using Python 3.7.3 and matplotlib 3.1.0.

What could be causing this?

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: Just `print(rs2[248:253])` should be enough to ascertain if it's a strange quirk of Matplotlib or a strange quirk of something else...

Comment: @gboffi I forgot to mention, one of the first things I did was to dump the data out as a CSV and import it into Excel. Both ellipses looked perfect there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have matplotlib version `3.4.1` and this is my output. Try to **update matplotlib**

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
or
conda update matplotlib
```

[image]